# How to remove a trailing comma from a string (Java)

Tags: java, formatting

I have an array, which I use a for each loop to iterate through. I then store it in a string and then try to add a comma to it, but am struggling look for a "logic" based solution.

I am almost close to about 1 year's worth of Java under my belt, so most of the solutions I am trying to find to implement are mostly logic based (for now), since this is apart of Java MOOC's course. What are some options I can look at? What am I missing?

```
for(int number: array){
    String thread = "";
    thread += number + ", ";
    System.out.print(thread);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the constraints of this project for your course, but if you're able, try a [StringJoiner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/StringJoiner.html)! It will add a delimiter automatically to separate items that are added to it. Another note, I think you're going to want to declare your String outside of your for loop. otherwise it resets every iteration.

```
StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",");
for(int number : array){
 joiner.add(String.valueOf(number));
}
     System.out.print(joiner.toString());
```

Comment: I thank you for your responses. Unfortunately, the first one didn't output the correct results, and the second one wouldn't compile since the int could not be de referenced (Per what the error said).

Comment: @wild_o Sorry about that I wasnt near a compiler! i updated the StringJoiner method it should work now

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Stream to achieve this result.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.stream(array).collect(Collectors.joining(",")));
```

Answer (score 0):

What I like to do when I'm just doing something simple and quick is this:

```
String thread = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    int number = array[i];
    thread += number;
    if (i < array.length - 1) {
        thread += ", ";
    }
}
```

Basically all it does is check that we aren't on the last index and append the comma only if it isn't the last index. It's quick, simple, and doesn't require any other classes.

Comment: This is a true logical solution. Very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Pressuming you had a string ending with a comma, followed by zero or more white spaces you could do the following.  `String.replaceAll()` uses a `regular expression` to detect the replacement part.

- `\\s*` means `0` or more white spaces
- `$` means at the end of the line

```
String str = "a, a, b,c, ";
str = str.replaceAll(",\\s*$","");
```

Prints

```
a, a, b,c
```